# Magento says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 4 in my code

Tags: php, magento

Magento says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 4 in my code. Not sure why. Any ideas?

```
public function itemIsVirtualGift($item){
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $_customOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);
    foreach($_customOptions['options'] as $_option){
        if (strpos($_option['label'], 'Is this a gift') !== false && strpos($_option['value'], 'Yes') !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() does indicate that the given iteration variable (in your case $_customOptions['options']) is not an iterateable object. Check what $_customOptions['options'] does contain to find whats wrong.

Comment: `$_customOptions['options']` may be `null` or empty array.

Comment: @teeyo if it was an empty array that error wouldnt occur, the foreach would just run zero times but there wouldnt be any errors. Beign NULL is a possible case tho.

Comment: @FabianSchöner yup, you're right, thanks.